# How could I better structure this code?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, simplify

Problem: Making my code better structured

What I've Tried: Putting common methods into methods

Issues: When putting common methods into methods the program breaks and no longer works

I am currently switching back and forth between two IDE's, Eclipse and IntelliJ. I also use Sublime to build small applications, so if any of the answers require any of these IDE's, I'm all set!

Thanks in advance for your responses, and if you have any issues or feel that I am lacking in certain areas of details, please do not hesitate to ask!

The Code:

```
package java_assignment;

// Bradley Duncan

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class textAnalyse extends Applet implements ActionListener {

    Label textBoxCaption;    //Caption for the text box
    TextField inputField; //Input field
    Button analyseButton;   //Analyse button
    Button resetButton;      //Reset button
    String inputText;
    int stringLength1, stringLength2, stringLength3, stringLength4, stringLength5, stringLength6, stringLength7, stringLength8, stringLength9;    //Variables with the string lengths stored for future comparison
    double MWL, StringCount, SLB1, SLB2, SLB3, SLB4, SLB5, SLB6, SLB7, SLB8, SLB9, SLB11, SLB22, SLB33, SLB44, SLB55, SLB66, SLB77, SLB88, SLB99;//used for working out coordinates


    public void init() {

        setSize(450, 350);

        textBoxCaption = new Label("Please enter your text here:");
        inputField = new TextField(35);
        analyseButton = new Button("Submit");
        resetButton = new Button("Restart");
        add(textBoxCaption);
        add(inputField);
        add(analyseButton);
        analyseButton.addActionListener(this);
        add(resetButton);
        resetButton.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("BWD", 425, 340);    // Puts my signature in the bottom corner
        inputField.setText("");
        inputText = ("");
        StringCount = 0;
        g.drawLine(50, 300, 410, 300);     //Drawing the x-axis
        g.drawLine(50, 300, 50, 50);       //Drawing the y-axis
        g.setColor(Color.red);                            //Setting the bar color
        g.drawRect(50, (int) SLB11, 40, (int) SLB1); //Drawing the bar
        g.setColor(Color.black);                   //Setting the text color
        g.drawString("1", 70, 315);                 //Giving values to the x-axis
        g.drawString("" + stringLength1 + "", 40, (int) SLB11);      //Displaying the frequency of the word on the y-axis
        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.drawRect(90, (int) SLB22, 40, (int) SLB2); //stringLength2
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString("2", 110, 315);
        g.drawString("" + stringLength2 + "", 40, (int) SLB22);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.drawRect(130, (int) SLB33, 40, (int) SLB3); //stringLength3
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString("3", 150, 315);
        g.drawString("" + stringLength3 + "", 40, (int) SLB33);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.drawRect(170, (int) SLB44, 40, (int) SLB4); //stringLength4
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString("4", 190, 315);
        g.drawString("" + stringLength4 + "", 40, (int) SLB44);
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.drawRect(210, (int) SLB55, 40, (int) SLB5); //stringLength5
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString("5", 230, 315);
        g.drawString("" + stringLength5 + "", 40, (int) SLB55);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawRect(250, (int) SLB66, 40, (int) SLB6); //stringLength6
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString("6", 270, 315);
        g.drawString("" + stringLength6 + "", 40, (int) SLB66);
        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.drawRect(290, (int) SLB77, 40, (int) SLB7); //stringLength7
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString("7", 310, 315);
        g.drawString("" + stringLength7 + "", 40, (int) SLB77);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.drawRect(330, (int) SLB88, 40, (int) SLB8); //stringLength8
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString("8", 350, 315);
        g.drawString("" + stringLength8 + "", 40, (int) SLB88);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.drawRect(370, (int) SLB99, 40, (int) SLB9); //stringLength9
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString("9", 390, 315);
        g.drawString("" + stringLength9 + "", 40, (int) SLB99);
        g.drawString("Mean word length is: " + MWL, 200, 330);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        inputText = inputField.getText();    //Sets a variable as the inputted text
        inputText = inputText.replaceAll("\\p{P}", ""); //Removes punctuation from the text
        for (String retval : inputText.split(" ")) {   //Splits the string by spaces
            StringCount += 1;      //Adds 1 to the string count
            if (retval.length() == 1)      
                stringLength1 += 1;
            if (retval.length() == 2)
                stringLength2 += 1;
            if (retval.length() == 3)
                stringLength3 += 1;
            if (retval.length() == 4)
                stringLength4 += 1;
            if (retval.length() == 5)
                stringLength5 += 1;
            if (retval.length() == 6)
                stringLength6 += 1;
            if (retval.length() == 7)
                stringLength7 += 1;
            if (retval.length() == 8)
                stringLength8 += 1;
            if (retval.length() == 9)
                stringLength9 += 1;
            MWL = ((stringLength9 * 9) + (stringLength8 * 8) + (stringLength7 * 7) + (stringLength6 * 6) + (stringLength5 * 5) + (stringLength4 * 4) + (stringLength3 * 3) + (stringLength2 * 2) + (stringLength1 * 1)) / StringCount;
            //^^^Working out the Mean Word Length
            SLB1 = ((250 / StringCount) * stringLength1);  //Working out the coordinates of each bar
            SLB11 = (300 - SLB1);
            SLB1 = (300 - SLB11);

            SLB2 = ((250 / StringCount) * stringLength2);
            SLB22 = (300 - SLB2);
            SLB2 = (300 - SLB22);

            SLB3 = ((250 / StringCount) * stringLength3);
            SLB33 = (300 - SLB3);
            SLB3 = (300 - SLB33);

            SLB4 = ((250 / StringCount) * stringLength4);
            SLB44 = (300 - SLB4);
            SLB4 = (300 - SLB44);

            SLB5 = ((250 / StringCount) * stringLength5);
            SLB55 = (300 - SLB5);
            SLB5 = (300 - SLB55);

            SLB6 = ((250 / StringCount) * stringLength6);
            SLB66 = (300 - SLB6);
            SLB6 = (300 - SLB66);

            SLB7 = ((250 / StringCount) * stringLength7);
            SLB77 = (300 - SLB7);
            SLB7 = (300 - SLB77);

            SLB8 = ((250 / StringCount) * stringLength8);
            SLB88 = (300 - SLB8);
            SLB8 = (300 - SLB88);

            SLB9 = ((250 / StringCount) * stringLength9);
            SLB99 = (300 - SLB9);
            SLB9 = (300 - SLB99);

        }
        if (e.getSource() == resetButton) {
            inputField.setText("");    //Resetting the datafields when reset is pressed.
            inputText = ("");
            stringLength1 = 0;
            stringLength2 = 0;
            stringLength3 = 0;
            stringLength4 = 0;
            stringLength5 = 0;
            stringLength6 = 0;
            stringLength7 = 0;
            stringLength8 = 0;
            stringLength9 = 0;
            MWL = 0;
            StringCount = 0;
        }
        repaint(); //Re-painting the applet
    }
}
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to ask this question.

Comment: It sounds like this might belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: First thing I noticed is the Class name. Should have first letter in uppercase. Lowercase is for method names. This is the Java convention :).

Comment: @TomFenech EXACTLY the same second... Not bad... :-)

Comment: Advice on how to restructure wouldn't be on topic for SO. We could help with a program that doesn't work but you haven't told us what the problem is. (Doesn't compile...? Exception gets thrown...? Wrong output...?)

Answer (score 1):

I am not a `pro` , but to start with, the Class name should be capitals as per convention. You could have used an array for your `int stringLength` 's and `double SLB` 's. The huge list of `drawString` , `setColor` and `drawRect` looks like a repetitive block so, a loop could make it cleaner. And i think an applet or swing application is supposed to have long lines of codes because compared to the other classes (although its not a mandatory), it provides the User Interface. So more detailed your interface more the lines of codes. You could split them in separate classes if you want

Answer (score 1):

Well,

you need to have a better focus on null-pointer-exceptions.

this should be a better start:

```
public strictfp class TextAnalyse extends Applet implements ActionListener {

    public static final String UNSET_TEXT = "";
    protected Label textBoxCaption = new Label("Please enter your text here:"); // Caption for the
                                                                                // text box
    protected TextField inputField = new TextField(35);
    protected Button analyseButton = new Button("Submit");
    protected Button resetButton = new Button("Restart");
    protected String inputText = UNSET_TEXT;
    private java.util.List<Integer> lengths = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    private java.util.List<Integer> slb = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    private java.util.List<Integer> slbCoord = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    protected double MWL;
    protected double stringCount;

    { // this is called after constructor-create
        analyseButton.addActionListener(this);
        resetButton.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public java.util.List<Integer> getLengths() {
        if (lengths == Collections.EMPTY_LIST) {
            lengths = new ArrayList<Integer>(9);
        }
        return lengths;
    }

    public String getInputText() {
        assert inputText != UNSET_TEXT; // prevent read unset text.
        return inputText;
    }
    .... yourcode
```

Note: Please use the getter "getLengths" instead of the field for overloading from superclasses others may plan another day.